# Renew CSS transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs, I want to slide the left one on refresh to the left out of the page, and when the mouse hits left edge I want the div to slide back right.

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8qxua9Lx/1/

The thing is that the CSS transition property works the first time, but it doesn't work the second time when I use transform again using jQuery. How can I solve this?

This is JS code:

```
var toggleEdges = function(width) {
                var end = true;
                var slideOutLeftEdge = function() {
                    $('.leftAnchor').attr('class', 'leftAnchor').addClass("slideOutLeftEdge").delay(1000).queue(function(){
                        $('.leftAnchor').removeClass('slideOutLeftEdge');
                        $('.leftAnchor').css('left', '-500px');
                        $('.leftAnchor').hide();
                        $(this).clearQueue();
                        $( this ).dequeue();
                    });
                };
                var slideInLeftEdge = function() {
                    $('.leftAnchor').show();
                    $('.leftAnchor').attr('class', 'leftAnchor').addClass("slideInLeftEdge").delay(1000).queue(function(){
                        $('.leftAnchor').removeClass('slideInLeftEdge');
                        $('.leftAnchor').css('left', '0');
                        $(this).clearQueue();
                        $( this ).dequeue();
                    });
                };
                var slideOutRightEdge = function() {
                    $('.rightAnchor').attr('class', 'rightAnchor').addClass("slideOutRightEdge").delay(1000).queue(function(){
                        $('.rightAnchor').hide();
                    });
                };
                var slideInRightEdge = function() {
                    $('.rightAnchor').show();
                    $('.rightAnchor').attr('class', 'rightAnchor').addClass("slideInRightEdge").delay(1000);
                };

                $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
                    if (event.pageX > width && $('.leftAnchor').is(':visible')) {
                        slideOutLeftEdge();
                    }
                    if (event.pageX < 10 && !$('.leftAnchor').is(':visible')) {
                        slideInLeftEdge();
                    }
                    if (event.pageX < window.innerWidth - width && $('.rightAnchor').is(':visible')) {
                        //slideOutRightEdge();
                    }
                    if (event.pageX > window.innerWidth - 10 && !$('.rightAnchor').is(':visible')) {
                        //slideInRightEdge();
                    }
                });
            };
            toggleEdges(500);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why yet, but it's never calling your queue function the second time.

Comment: Yes, that's the second thing I'm trying to figure out, the first thing is why the animation happens only on sliding left.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8qxua9Lx/4/ - after removing clearQueue() it kind of works, but the animations seems random.

Comment: I tried logging every time each function is called.  After the first cycle, it never stop firing on slideOutLeftEdge which means it's still visible.

Comment: yes I noticed that too.

Comment: So, what can be wrong? Why does changing class with different transition doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you've got here is based on the fact that your div is visible and you check for `!$('.leftAnchor').is(':visible')`.

I made some changes to reuse the jQuery objects instead of creating them every time you need them (`$leftAnchor` and `$rightAnchor`)

```
var toggleEdges = function (width) {
    var end = true;
    var $leftAnchor = $('.leftAnchor');
    var $rightAnchor = $('.rightAnchor');

    var slideOutLeftEdge = function () {
        $leftAnchor.attr('class', 'leftAnchor').addClass("slideOutLeftEdge").delay(1000).queue(function () {
            console.log("slideOutLeftEdge");
            $leftAnchor.removeClass('slideOutLeftEdge');
            $leftAnchor.css('left', '-500px');
            //$leftAnchor.hide();
            $(this).clearQueue();
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    };
    var slideInLeftEdge = function () {
        $leftAnchor.show();
        $leftAnchor.attr('class', 'leftAnchor').addClass("slideInLeftEdge").delay(1000).queue(function () {
            console.log("slideInLeftEdge");
            //$leftAnchor.removeClass('slideInLeftEdge');
            //$leftAnchor.css('left', '0');
            $(this).clearQueue();
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    };
    var slideOutRightEdge = function () {
        $rightAnchor.attr('class', 'rightAnchor').addClass("slideOutRightEdge").delay(1000).queue(function () {
            $rightAnchor.hide();
        });
    };
    var slideInRightEdge = function () {
        $rightAnchor.show();
        $rightAnchor.attr('class', 'rightAnchor').addClass("slideInRightEdge").delay(1000);
    };

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (event) {
        if (event.pageX > width && $leftAnchor.is(':visible')) {
            slideOutLeftEdge();
        }
        if (event.pageX < 10 && $leftAnchor.css('left') === '-500px') {
            slideInLeftEdge();
        }
        if (event.pageX < window.innerWidth - width && $rightAnchor.is(':visible')) {
            //slideOutRightEdge();
        }
        if (event.pageX > window.innerWidth - 10 && !$rightAnchor.is(':visible')) {
            //slideInRightEdge();
        }
    });
};
toggleEdges(500);
```

I updated your jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8qxua9Lx/6/

If that's what you need, then you can improve the code to make it working with the right `div`